# PATH issue with Cron - Not running bash/python script

Tags: 18.04, cron

I have been troubleshooting this command for two days, so any help is appreciated. I want to execute a Python script, which I understand must be done via a bash script, as cron does not run Python directly? I suspect I am not doing the PATH correctly, which makes the bash script run, but not the Python script.

I am trying to run the following command:

```
* * * * * bash /home/dpa/PycharmProjects/Parser/start_helper &>/tmp/mycommand.log
```

It does output the mycommand.log, so I know that it executes, but it does not start the python script. The .log file is blank.

The bash script is named start_helper without the .sh extension, as I read the crontab does not "like" punctuations. The only thing the script does is to start a python script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

python /home/dpa/PycharmProjects/Parser/Parser.py
```

I have assured the following:

1. Cron daemon is running
2. Permissions: I have tried running the script in terminal, and it works
3. The script is executable
4. Scripts are owned by root
5. PATH - an echo $PATH gives me the following:

   ```
    /home/dpa/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
   ```

The path that is output from cron displays the following:

```
LC_TIME=nb_NO.UTF-8
HOME=/home/dpa
LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8
LOGNAME=dpa
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LC_ADDRESS=nb_NO.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nb_NO.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nb_NO.UTF-8
PWD=/home/dpa
LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=nb_NO.UTF-8
```

Comment: Certainly, `cron` can run `python `directly, even without specifying its full path (unless you have installed several different `python`s). And certainly `cron` will run a script called `start_helper.sh`. I would simply put the `python` command in the `crontab` and make sure it can write its STDOUT and STDERR somewhere, like a log file.

Comment: Thanks @Jos. I tried writing the python command, but still with no result. The .log file is still blank, is &> the right syntax to output STDOUT and STDERR?

Comment: Whow, I actually got an output by using >> /tmp/mycommand .log 2>&1   /bin/sh: 1: python: not found - This would confirm my suspicion that it was a PATH issue?

Comment: Well, it is unusual that `python` is not found, as it is widely used tool in Ubuntu. However, replace `python` by `/usr/bin/python` and try again.

Comment: If Python cannot be found only for Cron, check your `PATH` variable inside the crontab.

Comment: After Googling, I added the following to crontab: PYTHONPATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin/python. it did not work, I will try with just PATH=

Comment: I have installed Anaconda, so I have two instances of Python

Comment: FYI `&>` is a bashism - cron runs its jobs in `/bin/sh` so it's treating it as two instructions (background the process, and write its standard *output* to the log file)

Comment: Still no luck, I have tried to Google setting PATH in cron, but I am not entirely grasping the concept. I have tried writing this line as the first line in crontab: PATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin/python:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: @Program Please [edit] your question to add details. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.